# Interpolating functions using Interpolations.jl and Dierckx.jl in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, interpolation

I am trying to carry out interpolation of function using the Interpolations.jl and Dierckx.jl packages in Julia. The doc of Interpolations.jl is as following:

https://github.com/JuliaMath/Interpolations.jl/blob/master/doc/Interpolations.jl.ipynb

And for Dierckx.jl:

https://github.com/kbarbary/Dierckx.jl

So I tried to experiment the interpolation using different functions, for example:
A simple code:

```
using Interpolations
xs = 0:5
f(x) = x^2 * abs(sin(3*x) + cos(x))
ys = f.(xs)
f_int = interpolate(ys, BSpline(Quadratic(Line(OnCell()))))
println("f(3.2) = ", f(3.2))
println("f_int(3.2) = ", f_int(3.2))
```

Quadratic interpolation is supposed to be quite accurate, however the result is as following:

```
f(3.2) = 12.007644743861604
f_int(3.2) = 2.973832923722435
```

So what have I misunderstood about the functionality of Interpolations.jl? The `interpolate` function in Interpolations.jl does not accept the array `xs` as argument but only `ys`, so I think it maybe due to my "incorrect" choice of `xs`?

Then I switched to Dierckx.jl, which accept both `xs` and `ys` in the functions `Spline1D` and `Spline2D`. It seemed to me `Spline1D` worked fine in the example as above, as I switched the line of the function interpolation to:

```
f_int = Spline1D(xs, ys)
```

Nevertheless, when I experimented with 2D, problems arose again:

```
using Dierckx
xs = 1:5
ys = 1:8
g = Float64[(3x + y ^ 2) * abs(sin(x) + cos(y)) for x in xs, y in ys]
f(x) = (3x + y ^ 2) * abs(sin(x) + cos(y))
f_int = Spline2D(xs, ys, g)
println("f(3.2, 3.2) = ", f(3.2, 3.2))
println("f_int(3.2, 3.2) = ", f_int(3.2, 3.2))
```

The result:

```
f(3.2, 3.2) = -0.6316251447925815
f_int(3.2, 3.2) = 20.578758429637535
```

So again, what's wrong with the code above? What have I misunderstood about the functionalities of these packages?

[Edit]
I tried to plot a contour to compare the interpolated 2D function produced by Interpolations.jl and the actual contour of the function, and this gives rise to the following result:

```
using Interpolations
using Plots
gr()

xs = 1:0.5:5
ys = 1:0.5:8
g = Float64[(3x + y ^ 2) for x in xs, y in ys]
f(x, y) = (3x + y ^ 2)

g_int = interpolate(g, BSpline(Quadratic(Line(OnCell()))))

gs_int = scale(g_int, xs, ys)

xc = 1:0.1:5
yc = 1:0.1:5

println("gs_int(3.2, 3.2) = ", gs_int(3.2, 3.2))
println("f(3.2, 3.2) = ", f(3.2, 3.2))

p1 = contour(xs, ys, gs_int(xs, ys), fill=true)
p2 = contour(xc, yc, f, fill=true)

plot(p1, p2)
```

[image: a]

There doesn't seem to be problems with the interpolated function for now by randomly choosing some values of (x, y), but why does the contour plot of the interpolated function look so distorted?

Comment: I changed f(x) above (your second example) to f(x, y) to get it to compile and got:  
 f(3.2, 3.2) = 20.964311357371095  
f_int(3.2, 3.2) = 20.578758429637535   which might be fine?

Comment: Oh I see! So the result was wrong probably due to my typo ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me focus on your attempt using Interpolations.jl, since it is a pure-Julia solution.

As you have anticipated, you need to scale the underlying grid appropriately. This is as simple as one extra function call (see [scaled BSplines](https://juliamath.github.io/Interpolations.jl/latest/control/#Scaled-BSplines-1) in the package documentation):

```
using Interpolations
xs = 0:5
f(x) = x^2 * abs(sin(3*x) + cos(x))
ys = f.(xs)
f_int = interpolate(ys, BSpline(Quadratic(Line(OnGrid()))))
sf_int = scale(f_int, xs) # new: scale the interpolation to the correct x-grid
println("f(3.2) = ", f(3.2))
println("f_int(3.2) = ", f_int(3.2))
println("sf_int(3.2) = ", sf_int(3.2)) # new: printing of the result
```

With this change you'll get

```
f(3.2) = 12.007644743861604
f_int(3.2) = 2.973832923722435
sf_int(3.2) = 7.353598413214446
```

which is closer, but still pretty bad. However, the reason is simple: the input data doesn't suffice for a good interpolation. Let's visualize this. With the current input data we have the following situation:

[image: before]

Now let us use a finer input data grid, `xs = range(0,5,length=20)`. With this change we have

```
f(3.2) = 12.007644743861604
f_int(3.2) = 0.6113243320846269
sf_int(3.2) = 12.002579991274903
```

and graphically

[image: after]

Clearly, the interpolation is now able to capture most characteristics of the underlying function.

Comment: Oh I see! And I would like to ask how should one scale the grid in 2D or in spaces of even higher dimensions?

Comment: It extends as expected: you just do `scale(f_int, xs, ys)` in 2D where `xs` and `ys` span the 2D grid. See the documentation linked in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you. But as I tried to make a contour plot out of the interpolated function, it looks distorted compared to the original function. Why is it so? (Please see the edited post)

Comment: If you define `fi(x, y) = gs_int(x, y)` and pass `fi` as a function you get plots that are much more similar. This is a difference in how `contour` works for array vs function input, not a feature of Interpolations.jl